# Excel macro populates a date cell but its not equal to a real date cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that returns an ODate (date in a double data type) from a called API.

```
Private Function CoreCompute(....)
   .... 
   CoreCompute = oXmlHttp.ResponseText //sample return: a double value 41902, which is equivalent to 2014/09/20
End Function
```

When this is called to a cell with a Format of Date, it is not transformed to a date value and not equal to a true date cell.

How can I output a value in a cell which can be compared to an actual date cell value?

PS. Q17 is actually Q16

[image: Simulation of the problem. Q17 is actually Q16]

Comment: Format the cell as a date. I mean, like dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: did it (as shown by the red arrow)

Comment: Nope. Right-click on the cell, select date formats, and then select the specific format that you wish. Alternatively, use the format brush,copy format from the cell above and paste format into the cell showing `41902`.

Comment: can you try using `CoreCompute = CDbl(Trim(oXmlHttp.ResponseText))`

Comment: I just tried what I suggested and you should get the date `20-Sep-2014`.

Comment: Sam's comment worked!

Comment: @Roj Beraña: Do you know why @Sam's comment worked? "`oXmlHttp.ResponseText //sample return: a double value`" is an oxymoron. `ResponseText` will return text as it says already. @Sam: Please write an answer.

Comment: @AxelRichter yup, kinda feel silly when I realized what his answer means.

Comment: Another point: If you have an expected return type, you should declare it in the function's signature, such as `Private Function Core_Compute(...) as Double`. In that case, it will automatically cast the value as a `Double`. If the return value is incompatible (for example, "ABCD"), then the function will throw an error which you can then handle.

Comment: @RojBeraña I added my comment as an answer. I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `CoreCompute = CDbl(Trim(oXmlHttp.ResponseText))`

This probably works because your response is a string and it could have whitespace included.

`Trim` will remove the whitespace

`CDbl` will ensure that value is converted to a number type.